# C++ dynamic array "losing" data

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic

So firstly, here's my declaration and initialization:

```
int** GameField = 0;
GameField = new int*[mapsize];                  
for(int i = 0; i < mapsize; i++)
        GameField[i] = new int[mapsize];

for(int j = 0; j < mapsize; j++)                
        for(int i = 0; i < mapsize; i++)
            GameField[i][j] = 0;
```

Now i'm trying to insert data with a simple command:

```
if(!(Player1.find(Move) == Player1.end()) && iter>0)            
        {
            GameResult=1;                                       
        }else
        {
            Player1[Move] = 1;                          
            GameField[Move.first][Move.second]=1;               
            if(WinCheck(Player1, Move, x, mapsize))
                GameResult = 1;
        }
```

Simoultaneously i insert the data into an STL map. Visual Studio has no native display for dynamic data, so i'm unable to view the content of the table. Tried watching memory but it's pretty hard to make sense of it. There is a part of program that seems to be working till a certain point:

```
    bool CheckIfMovePossible(int **GameField, pair <int,int> &Move, int MapSize)
{
    int x = Move.first;
    int y = Move.second;
    bool Neighbour = false;

    if(GameField[modulo(x+1,MapSize)][y]==(1||2))                       // po prawej
        Neighbour = true;

    if(GameField[modulo(x+1,MapSize)][modulo(y+1,MapSize)]==(1||2))
        Neighbour = true;

    if(GameField[modulo(x+1,MapSize)][modulo(y-1,MapSize)]==(1||2))
        Neighbour = true;

    if(GameField[x][modulo(y+1,MapSize)]==(1||2))                       // x
        Neighbour = true;

    if(GameField[x][modulo(y-1,MapSize)]==(1||2))
        Neighbour = true;

    if(GameField[modulo(x-1,MapSize)][modulo(y+1,MapSize)]==(1||2))     // po lewej
        Neighbour = true;

    if(GameField[modulo(x-1,MapSize)][y]==(1||2))
        Neighbour = true;

    if(GameField[modulo(x-1,MapSize)][modulo(y-1,MapSize)]==(1||2))
        Neighbour = true;

    return Neighbour;

}
```

It's supposed to check if there are any neighbouring data in the container. I calculate the values manualy and using the debugger, and in each case the program acts as if there is no data in requested location, while it must there for it is present in the map. Any info will be appreciated.

Comment: `1||2` is not doing what you think it is doing. Also you would be better off with a 1D array. Index it like this: `myArray[(y)*width+(x)]`

Comment: @user1928689 `1||2` is equivalent to `true`.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that what you wanted to do with code like this

```
if(GameField[modulo(x+1,MapSize)][y]==(1||2))
```

is this.

```
if ( GameField[modulo(x+1,MapSize)][y] == 1 ||
     GameField[modulo(x+1,MapSize)][y] == 2)
```

Unrelated to your question, it seems like your logic does *a lot of work* **after** it has been determined that the function will return `true`.

Consider using `else if` or having the code `return true` as soon as it's determined that that is the return value.

Comment: Thanks alot, helped :) had the else if structure still changed it while searching for mistakes

Answer (score 2):

Your if statements should be like this:

```
if(GameField[modulo(x+1,MapSize)][y] == 1 ||
   GameField[modulo(x+1,MapSize)][y] == 2)                       // po prawej
    Neighbour = true;
```

You also might want to save your modulo values so as not to have to recalculate them so often.

Comment: I vaguely remember being able to structure an if statement that way in VB6, but 'or' is a whole different beast in C++.